# Unexplained Call in C++ Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this constructor for a class:

```
10  REGION::REGION(const COORD &Default)
11  {
12     CELL temp(Default);
13     for(int x=0;x<100;++x)
14        interior[x]=temp;
15     Align();
16  }
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
Map.cpp: In constructor 'REGION::REGION(const COORD&)':
Map.cpp:10:36: error: no matching function for call to 'CELL::CELL()'
Map.cpp:10:36: note: candidates are:
Map.h:19:4: note: CELL::CELL(const COORD&)
Map.h:19:4: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Map.h:16:7: note: CELL::CELL(const CELL&)
Map.h:16:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I'm stumped. I'm guessing that, since the error is being placed between default and ) on line 10, the error is really on line 12. Howevere, line twelve should be a call to CELL::CELL(const COORD&), since Default is of type COORD. Why is the default constructor being called? I haven't defined a default constructor, but I can't imagine how that would be relevant to the situation.

Edit: This is the region class. I gather that the issue is interior, then?

```
class REGION
{
public:
   REGION(const COORD&);
   void Align();
   void MAlign();
   int x,
       y;
   CELL interior[100];
};
```

Comment: You should post your classes definitions. I'guessing `REGION` has a `CELL` field or array which must be constructed with `CELL`'s constructor

Comment: @Antoine: Guess so, too. The problem is *not* line 12.

Comment: I went in and defined the default constructors, which fixed the compiler error. However, the default constructor didn't actually do anything, so why did I have to define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the type of `interior` ?

If it's an array then the compiler must be able to create all elements with the default constructor before starting executing the `REGION` constructor code.

Answer (score 2):

Your class seems to have a field of type `Cell`. This field will be default initialized by using the constructor `Cell()` which does not exist. Thus, you must either create that constructor or initialize the field explicitly using the intializer list syntax, i.e.,

```
REGION::REGION(const COORD &Default) : YOUR_FIELD(Default) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have a member field of type 'CELL' and you haven't provided an initializer for it with the : (...) syntax before the body of the constructor starts.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, the arguments of the constructor for CELL are CELL(COORD Default) or CELL(COORD & Default)

but, you are passing a const reference, const COORD &Default. Please, post the CELL class header.

Comment: That wouldn't even be a *default* constructor.